# How to write Mocha test case for HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I am testing my `JavaScript` code with `Mocha / PhantomJS` setup to run the tests.

There is a function:

```
function getNodeClickWithExpand(idElement, treeName, autoCompleteName) {
    jQuery("input[type='checkbox'][name='c_" + idElement + "']").trigger("click");
    var treeView = jQuery("#" + treeName).data("kendoTreeView");
    treeView.expand(document.getElementById(idElement));
    jQuery("#" + idElement).closest("div").find("span:last").addClass("k-state-selected");
    kendoUiHoverAutoScrolling(idElement, treeName, autoCompleteName);
}
```

I am writing a test case for this function in `Mocha`:

```
describe("getNodeClickWithExpand", function () {
    it("should pass with correct inputs", function () {
        var processJsonObject = getNodeClickWithExpand(idElement, treeName, autoCompleteName);
        console.log(processJsonObject);
    });
});
```

when I run this test case it gives me an error. I know this is not correct.
Please tell me how to run `test case for HTML elements and events`.

**EDIT:**

Error I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Are you running the tests in the browser or cli ?

Comment: @1469 I am running test in both.

Comment: Have you included the Javascript file in which `getNodeClickWithExpand()` is defined?

Comment: @1469 yes I included the file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is here-

```
it("should pass with correct inputs", function () {
    var processJsonObject = getNodeClickWithExpand(idElement, treeName, autoCompleteName);
```

The test error 'Cannot read property 'expand' of null' indicates that there is no element in the dom with id = idElement. You need to pass an element's id as a string when you are running the test. You are also not passing any value for the parameters 'treeName' and 'autoCompleteName'.

Comment: 'treeName' and 'autoCompleteNmae' is already defined, and I am also passing idElement.

Comment: Could you run this test inside your describe block and check whether the test passes?  var domEle = document.getElementById(idElement);  it('Element exists in the DOM', function() {
    expect(domEle).to.not.equal(null);
  });

Comment: no I did not started bounty and my issue is still not solved.

Comment: Sorry, I checked; someone else gave me the bounty. Did you try out the test in my previous comment?

Comment: It definitely means that the var idElement contains a null value, or that there is no dom element in the page with the id value inside idElement. Try executing document.getElementById('<id of the element>') in the browser console, and check the output.